# AWS DynamoDB Query with start and end value

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to perform a query where I want to retrieve all the items that have height and width between 2 defined values like this:

```
let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()

queryExpression.filterExpression = ":widthSmall < #width < :width AND :heightSmall < #height < :height"
queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#addedByType = :addedByType"
queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = ["#addedByType": "addedByType", "#width": "widthSmall","#height": "heightSmall","#width": "width","#height": "height"]
queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":addedByType": "APPUSER", ":widthSmall": 50, ":heightSmall": 50, ":width": 100, ":height": 100]

queryExpression.scanIndexForward = false
queryExpression.limit = 200
```

This though throw the following error because of the expressionAttributeNames

```
fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys
```

What would be the correct way to check so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after quite a bit of trial and error I have figured out what I was doing wrong and came with the following result:

```
queryExpression.filterExpression = ":widthSmall < #width1 AND #width < :width AND :heightSmall < #height1 AND #height < :height"
queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#addedByType = :addedByType"
queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = ["#addedByType": "addedByType", "#width1": "width","#height1": "height", "#width": "width", "#height": "height"]
queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":addedByType": "APPUSER", ":widthSmall": 50, ":heightSmall": 50, ":width": 101, ":height": 101]
```

The problem was that I was referencing twice the same key in the dictionary